# Amazon RDS: Should I change the database parameter group values every time the instance type is modified?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I recently modified the instance type for an Aurora MySQL cluster.

I'm wondering if changing the instance type also requires adjusting parameter values in the parameter group in order to get a improvement in performance.

Since there are values that use formulas (e.g., the value of max_connections is GREATEST({log(DBInstanceClassMemory/805306368)*45},{log(DBInstanceClassMemory/8187281408)*1000})), I understand that these values are calculated based on the instance specifications, so it doesn't make sense to change them.

However, other values, such as sort_buffer_size, have fixed values, so I'm wondering if they should be modified based on the instance resources.

If so, which parameters should be adjusted manually?

The db instance type is db.t4g.medium.

I changed the database instance type from t4g.micro to t4g.medium, but I'm not sure if I need to change some parameter group values to get a improvement in performance.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL defaults and the defaults provided by Cloud providers are very good.  Do not worry about tuning anything until you have a specific use case that we can discuss.  Even in that case, adding a better composite index is the likely "fix" to a performance problem.

Old saying:  "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."